# making two object at the same time in java

Tags: java

I've made a class named 'Car'and I have this code.
`Car c=new Car(), yourCar;`
and I don't know what 'yourCar' means
Is is same as`Car myCar = new Car();  Car yourCar = new Car();`
?
I can't understand after the comma.

```
 package ex2_datatypecasting02;


class Car{
    String name = "car";
    String print() {
    return name;
    }
}
class Bus extends Car{
    String name = "bus";
    String print() {
    return name;
    }
}
public class CastingExam {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car myCar = new Car(),yourCar;
    Bus myBus = new Bus(),yourBus;
    System.out.println(myCar.print());
    System.out.println(myBus.print());
    yourCar = myBus;
    yourBus = (Bus)yourCar; 
    System.out.println(yourBus.print());
    } 
}
```

Comment: This should not compile. Where did you get that code?

Comment: @E_net4: this should compile. It simply declare additional variables for later.

Comment: Ouch, you are right. I have avoided this syntax for multiple declarations to the point of forgetting them.

Comment: And I am sure that there are tons of the same question already.

Answer (score 4):

You can **declare multiple variables** of the **same type** on one line by separating them with a comma (`,`). Like:

```
//declare three integers
int x, y, z;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
int x; // declare x
int y; // declare y
int z; // declare z
```

So here I have **declared three integers**, but I have **not initialized them**. You can also initialize one or more of them, like:

```
//declare three integers, initialize two of them
int x = 1, y, z = 4;
//  ^         ^ initialized
```

which is equivalent to:

```
int x = 1; // declare and initialize x
int y;     // declare y
int z = 4; // declare and initialize z
```

Here we have declared *three* variables, and initializes `x` and `z` with `1` and `4` respectively.

So the statement declares two `Car` variables: `c` and `yourCar`, and `c` is initialized with a new car, `yourCar` is **not**.

Answer (score 2):

As Willem well explained, this statement :

```
Car myCar = new Car(),yourCar;
```

is valid and allows to declare two `Car` variables but initializes only one of them : `myCar`. 
`yourCar` is indeed `null` here.

I would like to add that this way of doing spares you a line but is really error prone.
To get a better readability of your code, you should declare each variable on a distinct line :

```
Car myCar = new Car();
Car yourCar;
```

It produces the same result but it is much clearer.